# Any concept of iPhone Memory Store? memcache or redis for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm looking for some concept of a memory store for my iPhone App. There are some complex NSDictionaries I want to store in memory and read from, rather than parse the JSON stored in a database over and over.

If there is no such thing as a memory store, what options do I have? I tried putting inside user defaults, and reading it back again, but it seems to take just as long as the JSON parsing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to create a singleton class that contains the data I needed and it's being used by the entire app. Easy, simple and gets the job done

Answer (score 0):

Storing in a binary plist in persistent memory is faster than an xml plist.

Use the `NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0` option with `NSPropertyListSerialization`.